# Getting the row number of the N smallest value in a list using the small function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to dynamically sort a list of values for a helper column that looks something like this. I want to return the row number of the smallest value, then the next smallest, etc. The column on the right is what I want my output to look like. The formula I have so far is `=ROW(SMALL(A$1:A$15, A$2:A2)` but excel won't let me enter it.

[image: Example spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **B1** enter *1*.  In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="",9999,IF( COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)=0,A2,A2+COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)/100))
```

and copy downward.

In **C1** enter:

```
=MATCH(SMALL(B:B,ROWS($1:1)),B:B,0)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

**NOTE:**

Column **B** de-conflicts duplicate items in column **A** and handles the blanks in column **A**.

To limit the length of column **C**, use this instead in **C1**

```
=IF( ROWS($1:1)>COUNT(A:A),"",MATCH(SMALL(B:B,ROWS($1:1)),B:B,0))
```

Comment: Had to change a couple cell references but the core formula worked just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Excel O365 you could use a single formula in `C1` using [`SORTBY`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sortby-function-cd2d7a62-1b93-435c-b561-d6a35134f28f):

```
=SORTBY(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A),""),A:A,1)
```

[image]